# Pygame, rotating images by axis

Tags: python, rotation, 2d, pygame, physics

Im trying to rotate a loaded image but I need it rotated by a specific axis.

I was doing this:

```
arm  = pygame.image.load('w1.png').convert()
arms = [pygame.transform.rotate(arm, deg) for deg in range(0, 360, 4)]
```

I was then iterating through the indicies of arms with:

```
count+=1
arms[count]
```

The rotation does work but it is not rotating on the axis properly. I have written algorithms that rotate lines made with pygame.draw.line but I do not know how to achieve this with an image.

Any and all insight appreciated,

thanks

Comment: What is the problem that you are getting?

Comment: It doesn't rotate on the axis, it wobbles. Its a rectangle and I need a perfect 360 rotation on the point between the bottom left and bottom right points.

Answer (score 2):

After rotating your image, and before blitting, get the new rect for the image, and change the positional attributes of the rect back to the original position.

IE: save rect center, rotate image, get new rect, set newrect center, blit.

Using the center attribute with only rotate it around the center of the image, but maybe using one of the corners will put you on the right path.

```
def RESET_ROTATED_RECT(old_rect,rotated_image):
    old_pos=old_rect.center
    newrect=rotated_image.get_rect()
    newrect.center=old_pos
    return newrect
```

I use the center often, but haven't used the other positions. It may be worth tinkering with.

Comment: actually I just realized there appears to be something wrong with the function. All the 9 degree angles work, but on the 45s as well as others, the image changes it position for no apparent reason.

Comment: All the 90s stay on the axis and the 45s rotate correctly, but oscillate their co ordinance back and forth between another point.